# Save current document as .html with same name and path

Tags: save, applescript

I'm working on a [script](http://support.foldingtext.com/discussions/questions/357-script-to-generate-remark-formatted-html-file-form-foldingtext) for FoldingText which will convert a FoldingText outline (basically a Markdown Text file) into a [Remark](https://github.com/gnab/remark/) presentation (an HTML script which makes slideshows from Markdown files). The script works, but I'd like to make the following improvement:

Instead of asking for the name and location to save the HTML file, I'd like to grab the name of the current document and save it as an HTML file (with the same name) in the current folder. The script should fail nicely if there is already a document with that name (offering to either write-over the document or save as a new document with a different name).

The script I'm using for writing to the file was from these forums. The first part is:

```
on write_to_file(this_data, target_file, append_data) -- (string, file path as string, boolean)
try
    set the target_file to the target_file as text
    set the open_target_file to ¬
        open for access file target_file with write permission
    if append_data is false then ¬
        set eof of the open_target_file to 0
    write this_data to the open_target_file starting at eof as «class utf8»
    close access the open_target_file
    return true
on error
    try
        close access file target_file
    end try
    return false
end try
end write_to_file
```

And the second part is:

```
    set theFile to choose file name with prompt "Set file name and location:"
my write_to_file(finalText, theFile, true)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FoldingText should have some way of retrieveng the path of the document. I've not found any free dowonload fo the application, so I've not benn able to check by myself, but you should be able to find it if you view the dictionary of the application.

My guess is that there's a property like 'path of', or 'file of' for the FoldingText document:

You will probably end up with something like this:

```
set theDocPath to file of front document of application "FoldingText"
tell application "Finder"
set theContainer to container of theFile
end tell
set newPath to (theContainer & "export.html) as string
repeat while (file newPath exists)
set newPath to choose file name with prompt "Set file name and location:"
end repeat

my write_to_file(finalText, newPath, true)
```

Comment: Thanks to your help I got something close to what I was looking for. Currently there is no error handling and it simply appends HTML on to the full file name. A better script would offer to do "save as" if the file exists and would also strip the existing .md,.txt, or .ft extensions before appending .html. But this works fine for now. 

`tell front document of application "FoldingText"
    set thedocument to file of front document of application "FoldingText"
    set newPath to ((thedocument as string) & ".html")
    end tell
    my write_to_file(finalText, newPath, true)`

Comment: Hmm. It wouldn't let me format the code the way I wanted and after 5 min it told me I couldn't edit anymore. Here is a [link](http://support.foldingtext.com/discussions/questions/357-script-to-generate-remark-formatted-html-file-form-foldingtext#comment_25496591) to the revised script.

Comment: Note: this script will append, instead of overwriting the existing file if you run it twice, which creates problems. Need to avoid that somehow.

Comment: Ah, it was easily fixed by changing my write_to_file(finalText, newPath, true) to my write_to_file(finalText, newPath, false)!!!